# Are there algorithms to invert a magnitude spectrum?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, spectrum-estimation

I have a speech signal and have calculated the magnitude spectrum for the signal. Is it possible to get a good estimate of the original signal from the magnitude spectrum, seeing that phase information has been discarded after the FFT?

I have looked at the Wiener-Khintchine theorem, but I am unable to find any code examples of it in use, and I have not managed to get it to work.

Comment: A useful answer here: [Reconstruction of audio signal from Spectrogram](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/reconstruction-of-audio-signal-from-spectrogram/13401#13401).

Comment: Your question is very fundamental. What limit do you set to what you consider, and would use, as a spectrum? Which side information are you ok to  work on

Comment: For historical context: I believe that  Bode (or Bode plot fame) proved some theorems on this in the 1930's.  It involved assumptions like the all the poles in the left-hand plane and such, but was lucid and gave a constructive formula.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the stochastic literature, there are a set of deterministic algorithms that claim exact(?) recovery of a signal form its **partial** Fourier description, collectively referred to as:

> *signal reconstruction from DTFT phase or magnitude alone*

They are generally **iterative** in nature and exact convergence is hard to achieve in practice. Monson Hayes [et al] published relevant IEEE papers to propose several algorithms that reconstruct a **real** signal from its DTFT phase function alone, which is based on the phase sufficiency claim. The magnitude is a little more diffcult as I know. Have a look at those papers for your benefit.