# Inverse Short time fourier transform

Tags: fft, audio, discrete-signals, stft

I am I am working with 'wav' files in audio signal processing. I am able to find out STFT by using the function " spectrogram(file name, window length). Now I want to apply Inverse Short time fourier transform on the above signal. I tried "invspectrogram". but its showing error as Undefined function for input argument type of double. So please tell me how to proceed.

Comment: See here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/reconstruction-of-audio-signal-from-its-absolute-spectrogram/3410#3410

Answer (score 1):

A magnitude-only spectrogram is not invertible. The spectral phase required for reconstruction has been lost.

A complex FFT (a 1D column of spectrogram data before the absolute magnitude is taken and colored) might be (within numerical limitations) invertible by using an IFFT, but that won't recover the original signal if the STFT is using windowed FFTs.