# How to restore spectrogram to audio？

Tags: audio, python, spectrogram

I used the following code to convert the audio to spectrogram, now I try to get the spectrogram back to audio again, but don't know how to write the code.

```
import os
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2


def get_spectrogram(path):
    data, fs = librosa.load(path, sr=None, mono=True)
    spect = librosa.stft(data, n_fft=1024, hop_length=320, win_length=1024)
    return spect


def extract_features():
    i=0

    data_path = "./datasets"
    labels = ['mrdd0', 'mrso0', 'mrws0', 'mtjs0', 'mtpf0', 'mtrr0', 'mwad0', 'mwar0']
    # print("labels：", labels)

    total_data = []
    total_label = []

    for label in labels:
        label_path = data_path + "\\" + label
        # print(label_path)
        wav_names = os.listdir(label_path)
        for wav_name in wav_names:
            if wav_name.endswith(".wav"):
                wav_path = label_path + "\\" + wav_name
                # print(wav_path)
                spect = get_spectrogram(wav_path)
                spect = np.abs(spect)
                spect = cv2.resize(spect, (28, 28))
                total_data.append(spect)
                total_label.append(labels.index(label))
                plt.matshow(spect)
                plt.ylabel('Frequency')
                plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
                plt.title('Spectrogram')
                plt.savefig('./datasets/image_from_output/mySpectrogram-{}.png'.format(i))
                i=i+1

                #plt.savefig('./datasets/image/mySpectrogram.png')
                plt.close()
                plt.show()

    total_data = np.array(total_data)
    total_label = np.array(total_label)
    print(total_data.shape)
    print(total_label.shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extract_features()
```

Any help would be appreciated.It would be better if there could be code for conversion.

Comment: Also, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/reconstruction-of-audio-signal-from-its-absolute-spectrogram/3410#3410

Comment: (there's *several* questions on the topic here, and you're required to do research on your own!)

Comment: Note that an amplitude spectrogram throws away a lot of information, which you simply might not ever be able to restore. There's simply infinitely many different signals with the same spectrogram.